# Japanese to English OCR & Translation

Tags: ocr, translation

I am developing an app in which I have to convert Japanese text based images (computer & hand written) to English text. Currently I am using tesseract to convert image to text and then translating it via google translate. However I am not getting accurate results.

Is there any other OCR service/tool (paid or unpaid) that can read the image better? Also is google translate the best way to translate Japanese to English ?

Comment: You might check ABBYY FineReader. I have used it for many years with decent results from printed text. I haven't heard of any software to OCR handwritten Japanese though.

Comment: For the part about OCR of printed Japanese text, consider our [LEADTOOLS Recognition SDK](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/ocr). There's a free [evaluation edition you can download and try](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads?category=main), complete with free technical support.